# how to find value of key with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net

I have dictionary something like below :

```
{
 '0': ['a', 'b'],
 '1': ['c', 'd'],
 '2': ['e', 'f'],
 '3': ['g', 'h']
}
```

now, I need to find out the value of key 'g' if 'c' has a value 'd' and 'e' has a value 'f'
I tried using below way , but not working. Not getting how to pass multiple conditions

```
    var myKey = dict.Select(a => a.g.Value).Where(c.d && e.f);
```

please suggest

Comment: 'd', 'e', etc are not keys, they're values, aren`t?

Comment: I may be wrong but I just need value of key G from this dictionary if the condition is met. please suggest

Comment: None of `'c'`, `'d'`, and `'g'` are "keys" - they are items within arrays, which are _values_ in the dictionary. And `'g'` is in a different "value" that `c` or `d` so it's not clear at all what your condition is.

Comment: I have array which contains the dictionary items . now, from that dictionary , i want to find out the value of specific key . how can i do that ?

Comment: Please show us how you are creating `dict`

Comment: you have dictionary, you can iterate it with foreach - foreach(var item in dict){}(or LINQ as you did, but, i think this way will be easier to understand). And you have Key and Value inside of item in foreach. For example for first item key will be '0' and value will be ['a', 'b'], so this is the way you can manupulate with them, that is the only thing I can help you now, if you make you question more clear or provide more details I will understand what you wanna do

Comment: This question is very unclear as written. It would be a lot clearer if you provided c# code that populated the dictionary. What you wrote as a JSON snippet doesn't make sense with the question, as it is not clear whether things like `g` are values or if they are the names of properties.